# Evaluating $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac {e^{-1/x^2}}{x}$ without using L' Hôpital's rule

Tags: limits

Is there a way to evaluate

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac {e^{-1/x^2}}{x}$$

without applying L' Hôpital's rule? I've tried subbing $y = \frac {1}{x}$ and it did not work, and I also tried evaluating the expression by the exponent's Taylor's series expansion and still got no idea finding an upper limit to it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

Enforcing the substitution $x=1/y$ reveals

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}=\lim_{y\to \infty}\frac{y}{e^{y^2}}$$

Then, recall the elementary inequality $e^x\ge 1+x$ with $x=y^2$.

Comment: Hey there! ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat Hey there back!  Good to see you've returned Joe.  -Mark

Comment: Just intermittently - my current work requires a lot of commuting which cuts into fun time :-). Take care!

Answer (score 1):

$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac {e^{(-x^{-2})}}{x}
$

If
$f(x)
= \frac {e^{(-x^{-2})}}{x}
$,
$\ln f(x)
=-x^{-2}-\ln x
$.

If $0 < x < 1$,
$\ln x
=\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}
=-\int_x^1 \frac{dt}{t}
\gt -\frac{1-x}{x}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\ln f(x)
&=-x^{-2}-\ln x\\
&<-x^{-2}+\frac{1-x}{x}\\
&=\frac{-1+x-x^2}{x^2}\\
&\to -\infty \text{ as } x \to 0
\end{array}
$

so
$f(x) \to 0$
as
$x \to 0$.